# How to extract all span's on a page using iMacros?

Tags: javascript, csv, scripting, imacros

```
<span class="Fcontainer"><a href="http://www.codechef.com" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="return MN.openUrl(this);" class="external_link" data-qt-tooltip="codechef.com" data-tooltip="attached">Programming Competition,Programming Contest,Online Computer Programming</a></span>
<span class="Fcontainer"><a href="http://www.hackerrank.com" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank" onclick="return MN.openUrl(this);" class="external_link" data-qt-tooltip="hackerrank.com">HackerRank</a></span>
```

A number of span's with same class is there a webpage.

I am using

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:Fcontainer* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR4 {{!EXTRACT}}
```

*But I am only to save 1 entry to my csv file column, that is only "Programming Competition,Programming Contest,Online Computer Programming"*

How do I save all the span's with same class to csv file, with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Use Play Loop. Code is tested and works.
[image]

Comment: I think. My problem is need of inner loop. Could you guide me implement that.

Comment: Example of imacros javascript code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772406/how-to-stop-imacros-javascript-script

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data in the different columns in the same row instead of multiple rows and same column, you will have to implement Javascript code.

Get all of the data in an array and then save the array in the CSV.

In the CSV, The array data will be in one cell. So you will have to select the cell and split text on basis of comma. This will get the extracted data in the same row but different column.